# Songbird Alternatives

Tags: music, video-player

I like the [songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) player very much, and it used to be my only choice for all plataforms, but they have discontinued GNU/linux support for some time now, due to lack of people to help with the linux port.

I would like to know what are the alternatives with similar features and usability out there.

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki since there is not one right answer to it, and answers might be subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be worth keeping an eye on the [nightingale](http://getnightingale.com/) project.

They aim to continue to develop and maintain a Songbird version for linux.

Comment: when nightingale will release a Beta or Stable version, anybody knows?

Answer (score 6):

Banshee is the best. Amazon, ubuntu one, and ITUNES IMPORT plugins to start.

Answer (score 3):

I really like mpd, a music playing daemon. The idea is that you have the daemon running which can play music and you can connect with multiple clients. `ario` is a nice one, and `sonata` is a very nice simple one. You even have cli clients if that is your deal(it sure is mine), the best cli one is `ncmpcpp`, and I agree it's a shitty name

Comment: mpd has the lowest overhead and resource usage of any music player I've ever used

Answer (score 2):

[Rhythmbox](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/) is installed by default (*Applications > Sound & Video > Rhythmbox Music Player*)
[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) can be installed from the Software Center (*Applications > Ubuntu Software Center*) or from the terminal (`sudo apt-get install banshee`) or if your browser supports [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) links: `apt:banshee`

Answer (score 2):

[Clementine Music Player](http://www.clementine-player.org/): A very simple yet feature rich music manager.

Features:

- Search and play your local music library
- Listen to internet radio from Last.fm, SomaFM, Magnatune, Jamendo and Icecast
- Create smart playlists and dynamic playlists
- Tabbed playlists, import and export M3U, XSPF, PLS and ASX
- CUE sheet support
- Visualisations from projectM
- Lyrics and artist biographies and photos
- Transcode music into MP3, Ogg Vorbis, Ogg Speex, FLAC or AAC
- Edit tags on MP3 and OGG files, organise your music
- Fetch missing tags from MusicBrainz
- Download missing album cover art from Last.fm
- Native desktop notifications on Linux (libnotify) and Mac OS X (Growl)
- Remote control using a Wii Remote, MPRIS or the command-line
- Copy music to your iPod, iPhone, MTP or mass-storage USB player

[image]

Comment: It is really worth emphasising the ProjectM support for anyone that likes visualisations. It uses Milkdrop presets, for anyone that remembers those...

Answer (score 1):

I've become a huge fan of [Minitunes](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitunes). Minimalistic, still lacks advanced functionality, but its premise and direction are fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite player is Amarok, although it isn't particularly similar to Songbird..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I misunderstood the question.

I recommend [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/download/) for managing your music and playback.

**Note:** MediaMonkey is a Windows application, but according to the website, it runs fine under wine.

Answer (score 0):

If your after something similar to the filter panels found in Songbird and iTunes, [Guauadeque](http://alternativeto.net/software/guayadeque/?profile=linux&platform=linux) is probably more suited to former Songbird user.  Works pretty well for me, and is regularly updated. :-)